# The best approach to send data to a Partial View Model and .html() being slow

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

Imagine I have a Partial View with  a list of users ( loop ) where each user is another partial view with details about one.

```
foreach (var user in Model.Users)
 {
  <a href="#" onclick="JavascriptFunction(user.Id);">Details<a>
 }
```

When I click the above Details link for one of the list items a popup (JQuery modal dialog() ) pops up with details about that selected user. Or at least that's the goal. I need to get the selected user details to a new popup that opened.

So now I need to populate the model behind the partial view that  the popup will contain  with user details before .dialog('Open') triggers.

Question: What's the best way, from within a Javascript function ( onclick JavascriptFunction function in the example above) to call an ActionMethod and populate the Partial View model before the dialog is displayed ?

Right now I'm doing it the following way but for whatever reason I'm getting major delays in data being rendered on the page. I see blank div for good 5-10 seconds before .html() finally displays data:

On the main list page:

```
<div id="userPopup"></div>
```

Javascript that suppose to load Partial view with User details from an ActionMethod:

```
        $.post('@Url.Action("Details","User")', { id: userId},
        function (data) {

            $("#userPopup").html(data);
        });
```

Possibly there is a way to pre-load a partial view on the page and then just load my data into its Model without re-writing the entire PartialView ?
That would be the ideal scenario but I don't think there is a way to do it, is there ?

Thank you in advance ! Don't hesitate to ask questions if anything sounds confusing.

Comment: I can almost garentee the delay is coming from the `$.post`, not the `.html()` unless `data` is VERY large.

Comment: What about a `get` instead of a post? Any speed difference?

Answer (score 1):

I dont think you should preload all the user details on the main page, what if you have 1000+ users and the visitor is not clikcking the details link ! I would do it in this way. Whenever user clicks on the link, make a call to an action method which returns the data.

So in your main view,

```
@foreach(var user in Model.Users)
{
  @Html.ActionLink(user.Name, "Details", "User",
                             new { Id = user.ID, }, new { @class ="popupLink" })

}

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $(".popupLink").click(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var url = this.href;
        var dialog = $("#dialog");
        if ($("#dialog").length == 0) {
            dialog = $('<div id="dialog" style="display:hidden"></div>').appendTo('body');
        }
        dialog.load(
            url,
            {}, // omit this param object to issue a GET request instead a POST request, otherwise you may provide post parameters within the object
            function (responseText, textStatus, XMLHttpRequest) {
                dialog.dialog({                       
                    close: function (event, ui) {                            
                        dialog.remove();
                    },
                    modal: true,
                    width: 460
                });
            }
        );         

    });
});
</script>
```

In User controller, have an action method called "Details which accepts the Id as parameter and return the View of User details

```
public ActionResult Details(int id)
{
  var usre=repositary.GetUser(id);
  return View(user);
}
```

Have your HTML markup for details in the DetailsView.

This code use jQuery UI model dialog. So you need to include that.

Comment: Thank you Shyju. I can't understand what are you doing to make the returned information open in a popup instead of a brand new View. In fact that's exactly what happens now after I implemented your logic.
ActionMethod gets called and returned View takes over the whole screen instead of being in a modal popup.

I should mention that I already have my dialog properties declared in a different place.

Comment: @Shenaniganz: you have to prevent the default behaviour (of the target of link being loaded in the browser). I updated my answer to use preventDefault function and make sure you have no script errors there. use firebug and see what is the error.